# will my 6 digit number code work?

Tags: python

i need to generate all 6 digit number for a word list 
will this code work?

```
from random import randint
list = [111111]
print ('111111')
while True:
    number = randint(100000,999999)
    if not number in list:
        list.extend(str(number))
        print(number)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do here.  You want a list of all 6 digit #s?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly trying out numbers and then adding them one character at a time (look into `append()` rather than `extend()`), simply send the `range()` object to `list()`:

```
numbers = list(range(100000, 1000000))
```

Note that I've called it `numbers` rather than `list`, to avoid masking `list()`.

If you want each number as a string, map them to strings:

```
numbers = list(map(str, range(100000, 1000000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method would work but would be very slow. I would suggest using list comprehension to generate the list of numbers. If you need it to be randomized, there is a shuffle method as part of the random module.

```
from random import shuffle

#if you wanted just numbers
x_all_numbers = [i for i in range(100000, 999999)]

#if you wanted strings of different numbers
x_str_numbers = [str(i) for i in range(100000, 999999)]

print(x_all_numbers[0:10])
shuffle(x_all_numbers)
print(x_all_numbers[0:10])
```

To show that this will work, I included the output:

```
[100000, 100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005, 100006, 100007, 100008, 100009]
[783780, 170070, 270425, 119709, 194098, 617834, 740368, 420370, 993130, 712673]
```